# Google Wallet Payment Settings

Tags: android-pay

I'v been trying to change my Wallet Payment Settings. It's settled that the payment must be Monthly.
Does anybody know how to change it to get paid every 6 months?
Here is a picture showing the Payment Schedule.
[image]

*mensal = monthly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a technical question.  But I'll answer it here anyway.

To the best of my knowledge there's only one payout schedule for Android/Google Wallet for Digital Goods developers and that's monthly.  Here's the help center article for more info:

https://support.google.com/payments/answer/3092796?hl=en